# multiple SurfaceView render targets and vsync

Tags: android-ndk

My goal is to show multiple (small) panes of video on-screen simultaneously.

I would prefer to use the hardware scalar. This is currently working well for a single video on a single surface. For multiple streams it appears multiple SurfaceViews are needed - I don't see a way to use the hardware scaler to blit multiple images into different parts of the same Surface.  What's the best way to lock/blit image pixels to these surfaces?

**ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost** causes a wait-for-vsync + swap (I think?), so I can't call this per-SurfaceView in the same update cycle (well I can, but I get horrible jittering).

One alternative is to use a seperate render thread per SurfaceView. Does this seem like a sane avenue to pursue? Are there any other ways to update multiple SurfaceViews with a single wait-for-vsync+swap?

Comment: How is your video arriving?  Can you send them to SurfaceTextures and render them with GLES to a single GLSurfaceView?

Comment: frames arriving via ffmpeg avpicture_fill. Your idea is intriguing...can I "send" them to a SurfaceTexture without scaling on the CPU?

Comment: Ah, if the frames are arriving in software buffers, you don't want to use `SurfaceTexture`.  You can instead bind each source to a separate texture ID, and use `glTexImage2D` to upload the frame.  At draw time, you just draw N rects, one at a time, binding the appropriate texture.  GL will do whatever scaling is appropriate during rendering.

Comment: Thanks. Does this work efficiently with non-power-of-2 size frames?

Comment: Maybe.  GLES2 supports NPOT textures with certain restrictions.  If it's a problem, you can work around it -- see e.g. both answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073611/possible-to-glteximage2d-an-npot-image-onto-a-pow-2-texture-without-extra-alloca .